# How can I display desktop-dirname in the modeline (or elsewhere)?

Tags: mode-line, desktop

I often get confused about the current desktop I'm using. Currently, I have to call `(display-variable desktop-dirname)` to see in which desktop I'm working.

It would be much nicer, if the current desktop would be displayed somewhere. The modeline seems to be ok for that.

How can I do that?

Comment: See [Mode Line Format](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Format.html#Mode-Line-Format) for the gory details of modifying the mode line. See [Header Lines](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Header-Lines.html#Header-Lines) for an alternate location of where to put bits of information.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning header lines! I'll stick with a much easier solution, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple solution turned out to be:

```
(defun mg-desktop-message ()
  "Show the current desktop dirname in the minibuffer."
  (interactive)
  (message "Current desktop: %s" desktop-dirname)
  )
```

Bound to a convenient key. I don't need it all the time, but if I do it's very handy.